# Volume doesn't reflect data

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ghost-blog

When I created my installation like this:

```
sudo docker run -d --name myBlog -p 3001:2368 -e url=http://xxxx.com -v /var/www/myBlog/:/var/lib/ghost --restart always ghost
```

I was under the impression that I was defining that what ever is on `/var/lib/ghost` would be available in `/var/www/myBlog/` but it seems that's not the case, when I check on `/var/www/myBlog/` there is an empty folder. I created a new post so it can have some data but nothing is there. 
Where exactly is the data being stored then? And is there a way I can access my current image that I'm using to see the files inside? I tried `sudo docker run -it ghost` but that gets me to the base image, not the one I'm using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please run the below command and you should be able to see files under target directory

```
docker run -d  -e url=http://xxxx.com --name some-ghost -p 3001:2368 -v "$(pwd)/target":/var/lib/ghost/content ghost:1-alpine
```

Comment: So does this creates a link from some folder inside the container to my host?

Comment: This mounts the host directory into the container which enables the container to access the data present in that folder on the host and vice versa

Comment: When I run it, I don't see on the host the files created by docker :/

Comment: If you want to see the files on the host created by container, please use `-v` flag

Comment: Edited my answer, please have a look and it should work

Comment: The -v flag is not doing anything, this is my command: `sudo docker run -d --name myBlog3 -p 3003:2370 -e url=http://example.com -v /home/ubuntu/content:/var/lib/ghost --restart always ghost` and when I go to `/home/ubuntu/content` it's empty while `/var/lib/ghost` is full of files...

Answer (score 0):

Volumes work the other way around. The source is mapped into the container, mounted on top of whatever exists in that directory inside the container. When you mount over an existing directory in Linux, the parent filesystem at that location is no longer visible.

That means you'll see the host directory contents inside the container. Note this also includes filesystem permissions, and uid/gid ownership.

Named volumes (not the host volume used here) also feature an initialization step for an empty volume when the container is created, copying image contents to the volume before mounting it. It will not modify an existing volume.

Comment: So the question is, how can I create a link from some folder inside the container to my host? I want to be able to see the data inside the container